# Android 10 (Android Q): How to unzip file due to External Storage Changes (without android:requestLegacyExternalStorage)

Tags: zip, unzip, android-10.0, zipoutputstream, zipinputstream

Can the Android 10(Android Q) download the zip file and extract the zip file?

I really have no idea. How do I unzip the file without using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

without adding this `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Please HELP.

Comment: Use `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, or similar methods on `Context` for a directory that you can write to.

Comment: Thanks, I use `getExternalFilesDir()` to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()`